# how to save JSON data after a http Post request in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http, local-storage

Hello guys here is my  `http post` code

```
createPost(input:HTMLInputElement){
    // input.value='';
    let post={content:input.value};
    let head = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({headers: head});
    let body = JSON.stringify(post);

    this.http.post(this.url,body,requestOptions)
      .subscribe(response => {
        post['id']=response.json().id;
        this.posts.splice(0,0,post);
      });
```

after a successfull `http post` request my server responds with a token for authentication to make that request, the token would be in *JSON* format. Now is there any way where I can get that token in real time and store it in local storage directly after a `http post` call

I can understand the concept of `localStorage.getItem()` and all but don't know where to implement them exactly to the context of my code 
this question might be so dumb to you but I'm just beginner in Angular

Comment: Don't really understand the question? Simply do a localStorage.setItem('myToken', theToken), right after the response

Answer (score 1):

You can have an `LoginService` which gets your token and saves it in the `localStorage`. It also can have another method with name `isAuthenticated` which verifies client is authenticated or not. When you have done the request

```
this.http.post(this.url,body,requestOptions)
         .subscribe(response => {
            post['id']=response.json().id;
            this.posts.splice(0,0,post);
            // Here you need to store the token in the localStorage
            // localStorage.setItem('access_token', yourToken)
         });
```

you need to store the token in the localStorage and then use this service to do next operations related to the token.

Another methods can look like

```
getToken() : string {
   return localStorage.getItem('access_tojen');
}

isAuthenticated() : boolean {
   const token = getToken();
   return /* your logic here */.
}
```

You can also look at a post about [**Authentication**](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/23/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial).

Comment: directly how  can i get the token  like grabbing the token using  after a http post request  how the code would look like

Comment: Mounikesh:
lets take an example http.post(example.com/token) and now user is logged in and token is visible for him in the token of my site now angular  should should get that token  and save it to localstorage in real time

Comment: There are libraries which decode your token and get the payload from it. For first you need to get the token.

Comment: no need to decode or anything just the token is enough to authenticate users

Comment: But maybe you also need for example `name` of the user, or `role` - I mean that

Comment: server will take care of everythin  , user  can use that token to perform crud operations to  do crud objects

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: here in yout code beside acess_token  in set token should i add get token() function ,does it work

Comment: getToken is just a comfort for another functions